# Listing Upload App on Mobile

Tags: android, listview, mobile

I need to show the installed applications in the listview on the mobile device how can I have info or suggest a source thank you

Comment: did my answer work to you?

Comment: Successful. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the function `getInstalledApplications()` from [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

Then using this :

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages =  pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
 Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
 Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
 Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
```

You have all of the applications, well.. that's how to do it as a "fast way", yes, you can do it creating a `ListView` with an `Adapter` and so, but for this, I recommend you to check this tutorial [how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android) it's a great example to do this.

Comment: Successful. Thank you very much

Comment: @OnurÖnder Perfect, Glad to hear it :)